# Exception in thread "main", mirrorHorizontal class in Picture.java and PictureTester.java?

Tags: java, image

Here I have a class written alongside many other functioning classes in Picture.java. My APCS curriculum packet that requires "a picture must be split along the horizontal, and the bottom mirrored to resemble the top" for this class.

I have imported the following:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.font.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.List;
```

and here is the code:

```
    public void mirrorHorizontal()
   {
      Pixel[][] pixels = this.getPixels2D();
      Pixel bottomPixel = null;
      Pixel topPixel = null;
      int height = pixels[0].length;
      for (int col = 0; col < pixels.length; col++)
      {
         for (int row = 0; row < height / 2; row++)
         {
            bottomPixel = pixels[(height - 1 - row)][col];
            topPixel = pixels[row][col];
            bottomPixel.setColor(topPixel.getColor());
         }
      } 
   }
```

In PictureTester.java, I have:

```
 /** Method to test mirrorHorizontal */
   public static void testMirrorHorizontal()
   {
    Picture caterpillar = new Picture("caterpillar.jpg");
    caterpillar.explore();
    caterpillar.mirrorHorizontal();
    caterpillar.explore();
   }
    testMirrorHorizontal();
```

written in order to display caterpillar.jpg, and then display it in a separate window with the horizontal mirror in effect. The picture is 150x329 pixels.

The two compile fine, and seem to be in order, but when i click Run on PictureTester.java, only the original caterpillar.jpg is displayed, and this error is returned:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 328
    at Picture.mirrorHorizontal(Picture.java:155)
    at PictureTester.testMirrorHorizontal(PictureTester.java:16)
    at PictureTester.main(PictureTester.java:113)
```

The GUI I'm required to use is jGrasp.

Comment: Please point out line# **155** in your `Picture.java` file.

Answer (score 1):

You have to swap `col` and `row`, as you have misplaced them

```
for (int col = 0; col < pixels.length; col++) {
     for (int row = 0; row < height / 2; row++) {
        bottomPixel = pixels[col][(height - 1 - row)];
        topPixel = pixels[col][row];
        bottomPixel.setColor(topPixel.getColor());
     }
 }
```